# Equivalent definitions of tensor product of two modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a right $R$-module and $B$ a left $R$-module.

Definition 1. Let $F$ be the free abelian group on the set $A\times B$. Let $K$ be the subgroup generated by all elements of the following forms (for all $a,a’ \in A$; $b,b’\in B$; $r\in R$): (i) $(a+a’,b)-(a,b)-(a’,b)$; (ii) $(a,b+b’)-(a,b)-(a,b’)$; (iii) $(ar,b)=(a,rb)$. The quotient group $F/K$ is called the tensor product of $A$ and $B$. The coset $(a,b)+K$ is denoted $a\otimes b$.

From this definition, follows the relations: 1) $(a+a’)\otimes b=a\otimes b + a’\otimes b$, 2) $a\otimes (b+b’)=a\otimes b + a\otimes b’$, 3) $ar\otimes b=a\otimes rb$ for all $r\in R$.

Definition 2. The tensor product of $A$ and $B$ is the abelian group with generators all symbols $a\otimes b$ ($a\in A, b\in B$), subject to the relations above.

I wish to show that these two definitions agree. I considered the typical map between these two definitions taking the symbol $a\otimes b$ to $(a,b)+K$. This map is clearly surjective and I could prove its well definedness as well, but I confronted a problem as to injectivity. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your definitions aren't merely equivalent, they're actually identical. By which I mean: examine what Definition 2 actually means.

"Definition 2. The tensor product of $A$ and $B$ is the abelian group with generators all symbols $a \otimes b$ ($a \in A, b\in B$), subject to the relations above."

But this just means that $A \otimes B$ is the quotient of the free abelian group on the set $\{a \otimes b: a \in A, b \in B\}$ modulo the subgroup generated by relations of the forms 1, 2, 3. But there is no difference between using the set of symbols $\{a \otimes b: a \in A, b \in B\}$ as the generating set and using $A \times B$, at which point we are just at Definition 1.